# integrate dropdown menu inside every list item in angular 7 and getting value

Tags: angular

Here I want to integrate dropdown menu in side of list with every item.I did try for same then when I select dropdown menu it will display name all list item

```
enter code here


this.productArrDummy=[
      {"id":1,"productName":"bag1"},
      {"id":2,"productName":"bag2"},
      {"id":3,"productName":"bag3"}
    ]
    this.dropdownArrDummy=[
      {"id":300,"deliveryBoy":"ABC"},
      {"id":400,"deliveryBoy":"MNO"},
      {"id":500,"deliveryBoy":"PQR"},
    ]
<div *ngFor="let item of productArrDummy;let i = index" style="display:flex;flex-direction: column;">
<p>{{item.productName}}</p>
<div>
  <mat-form-field >
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Delivery Boy" [(ngModel)]="promoMerCatType"  (selectionChange)="onCatChanged(promoMerCatType)">
      <mat-option  *ngFor="let boy of dropdownArrDummy; let j = index" [value]="boy"  >
          {{boy.deliveryBoy}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxNB2.png)

Comment: Hi Amit, You need to add few more details about the issue you are facing. It will be good, if you could add a minimal working logic with the exact code part of your issue.  So it will be easier for the others to test analyse your issue and also you will get a solution much faster. From the image only, no one can guess, what you might have bind to the dropdown elements.

Comment: Hello thanks for suggestion,Please check code sample